# Matriz NxM (2D) em Python com Numpy

Tags: python, matriz, numpy

Estou tentando resolver uma atividade da faculdade mas não consegui transpor a lógica para o código.
O case é o seguinte:
"O usuário irá informar dois números inteiros. Estes números inteiros irão determinar o tamanho da matriz. O usuário irá passar os inteiros na mesma linha separado por espaço.
Após o usuário passar os valores, os valores seguintes serão utilizados como dados da matriz.

**Ex.:**

```
2 2
3 4
5 6
```

*array* será `([3, 4], [5, 6])`

ou seja, uma matriz 2 x 2.

Comment: E qual foi a lógica que pensou? Poderia descrevê-la?

Comment: Eu entendi o que foi pedido, mas minha dificuldade é justamente essa, aplicar uma lógica pra isso.

Comment: Agora que olhei minha pergunta, vi que havia colocado que não conseguia aplicar a lógica ao código, mas na realidade meu problema é criar uma lógica para aplicar no código...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Você precisará ler a entrada do usuário, a fim de identificar qual será a dimensão da matriz. Faça isso utilizando a função [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#input);

   a. O retorno da função `input` será sempre uma *string*, então precisará converter sua *string* para uma sequência de dois números inteiros. Faça isso com apoio do método [`string.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) e [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#int);
2. Possuindo as dimensões da matriz, NxM, você terá que ler N vezes a entrada do usuário, que serão as linhas da matriz. Novamente use a função `input` para ler a entrada e repita o processo com um laço de repetição. Recomendo fazer com a estrutura [`for`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) com apoio da função [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#func-range);

   a. Novamente, lembre-se que o retorno de `input` sempre será uma *string*, então utilize a mesma lógica de 1.a para convertê-la em uma sequência de números;

**Dicas:**

1. Uma matriz pode ser representada como uma lista de listas;
2. Você pode inicializar uma lista vazia como `lista = []`;
3. Você pode adicionar novos elementos em uma lista com `lista.append(...)`;
4. Você pode acessar um determinado índice na lista com `lista[i]`;

---

Visto que você tentou fazer, colocarei um exemplo em código:

```
import numpy

dimensions = input('Dimensões da matriz NxM: ').split()
N, M = [int(value) for value in dimensions]

matrix = []

for i in range(N):
    row = input(f'Linha {i+1}: ').split()

    if len(row) != M:
        raise Exception(f'Você precisa informar {M} valores por linha')

    numbers = [int(number) for number in row]
    matrix.append(numbers)

matrix = numpy.matrix(matrix)

print(matrix)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/TrustyDistortedExecutable) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/8f4a29606036cd7f6e1d3f315269d0fb)</sup>

Um exemplo da saída gerada é:

```
>>> Dimensões da matriz NxM:  2 2
>>> Linha 1:  1 2
>>> Linha 2:  3 4
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui fazer desta forma, mas não é usando o padrão de lista que eu quero, preciso usar os recursos do numpy.

```
import numpy as np
lista = []
matriz = input("Informe as dimensões da Matrix: ").strip().split()
N = int(matriz[0])
M = int(matriz[1])
for i in range(N-1):
    for j in range(M):
        a = input().strip().split()
        a1 = int(a[0])
        a2 = int(a[1])
        lista.append(a1)
        lista.append(a2)
print(lista)
```

Comment: Eric, visto que você demonstrou ter tentado fazer, adicionei na minha resposta um exemplo de como o código ficaria. Veja se lhe atende e qualquer dúvida pode perguntar.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde @Anderson!

Agora a tarde, fiz o código após lê o seu. Seguindo a minha própria lógica, para aprender mais. O resultado do código foi o seguinte:

```
import numpy as np
dimensoes = input().strip().split()
N,M = (int(value) for value in dimensoes)
matriz = []
for i in range(N):
    a = input().strip().split()
    if i < M:
        for j in range(M):
            a1 = a[j]
            a1 = (int(a1))
            matriz.append(a1)
    else:
        print("ERROR")   
matriz = np.array(matriz)
print(matriz)
print(np.transpose(matriz))
print(matriz.flatten())
```

o problema agora é que os métodos transpose() e flatten() não estão funcionando como deveriam.

Answer (score 0):

Para que, caso outras pessoas tenham o mesmo problema, estou colocando a solução que criei para o meu próprio problema que atende em 100% o meu case.

```
import numpy as np
dimensoes = input().strip().split()
N,M = (int(value) for value in dimensoes)
matriz = []
for i in range(N):
    if i < M:
        a = input().strip().split()
        matriz.append(list(map(int, a)))
    else:
        print("ERROR")
matriz = np.array(matriz)
print(matriz)
print(matriz.transpose())
print(matriz.flatten())
```

Comment: Por que a condição `i < M`? Não pode existir uma matriz 6x2, por exemplo?

Comment: Estou criando uma matriz NxM, se I não for menor que M, levando em consideração que "i=0"  e "M=0" por exemplo, não conseguirei ter uma matriz 2D.

Após sua colocação, vi que eu precisaria ampliar o escopo do meu código para tratar alguns tratamentos. Por conta disso, ampliei meu código, vou postar uma nova resposta.

Comment: Mas `i` irá variar de 0 a N-1. Se N > M, é certeza que haverá o caso de i > M. Por isso citei o exemplo de 6x2, o valor de i variará de 0 a 5, enquanto M é 2, mas mesmo assim você terá uma matriz 2D (6x2). Essa condição não fez sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Segue novo código com tratamentos:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
def mat(a):
    a1 = a
    a1 = list(map(int, a1))
    matriz.append(a1)
    return matriz

dimensoes = input().strip().split()
N,M = (int(value) for value in dimensoes)
matriz = []
saida = 0
for i in range(N):
    if saida == 1:
        break
    a = input().strip().split()
    if len(a) > M:
        print("Tamanho de N informado é maior que Dimensão inicial de N!")
        saida = 1
        break
    elif len(a) > N:
        print("Tamanho de M informado é maior que Dimensão inicial de M!")
        saida = 1
        break
    else:
        mat(a)
if saida == 0:
    matriz = np.array(matriz)
    print(np.transpose(matriz))
    print(matriz.flatten())
```